# Removing empty elements from an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, io

```
with open("text.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n' + '').split(':')
        print(line)
```

I am having trouble trying to remove empty lists in the series of arrays that are being generated. I want to make every line an array in `text.txt`, so I would have the ability to accurately access each element individually, of each line.

The empty lists display themselves as `['']` - as you can see by the fourth line, I've tried to explicitly strip them out. The empty elements were once filled with new line characters, these were successfully removed using `.rstrip('\n')`.

**Edit:**

I have had a misconception with some terminology, the above is now updated. Essentially, I want to get rid of empty lists.

Comment: Technically `['']` is not an empty list. It's a list with one empty string in it. And your comment on Games' answer suggests that you somehow want to capture the empty values from your list? I think the most important question is: whatever for? There are better ways to simply count.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since I can't see your exact line, its hard to give you a solution that matches your requirements perfectly, but if you want to get all the elements in a list that are not empty strings, then you can do this:

```
>>> l = ["ch", '', '', 'e', '', 'e', 'se']
>>> [var for var in l if var]
Out[4]: ['ch', 'e', 'e', 'se']
```

You may also use `filter` with `None` or `bool`:

```
>>> filter(None, l)
Out[5]: ['ch', 'e', 'e', 'se']
>>> filter(bool, l)
Out[6]: ['ch', 'e', 'e', 'se']
```

If you wish to get rid of lists with empty strings, then for your specific example you can do this:

```
with open("text.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n' + '').split(':')
        # If line is just empty
        if line != ['']:
            print line
```

Comment: What exact line would you like to see? An example of one of the outputs? If so...

Comment: ['123', '123', '1039', '123', '123', '123', '123']
['']

Comment: @user2296349 Thats not exactly one list, now is it?

Comment: @user2296349 Check if that works for you. I updated it to match your question.

Comment: Sorry, Games. Was cleaning kitchen. Yes, it does! Thank you for your tolerance with me. You helped me identify my issue more clearly and of course, reach a working solution!

Comment: @user2296349 Happy to have been of service :)