# Scrape any string with Python + Beautiful Soup that contains 5 numbers

Tags: python, regex, scrape

Im living in Germany, where ZIP Codes are in most of the cases a 5 digit number f.e. 53525. I would really like to extract that information from a website using beautiful Soup.

I am new to Python/Beautiful Soup and I am not sure how to translate "Find every 5 Numbers in a row + "SPACE"" into Python language.

```js
import requests
import urllib.request,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('DOMAIN').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
soup.find_all(NOTSUREHERE)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data?

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest scenario:

`NOTSUREHERE`should be replaced by `name = 'tag_name'`, being `tag_name` a possible tag in which you are certain to find ZIP codes (and no other numerical field that could be mistaken by a ZIP Code)

Then, each element of that object should be passed to `re.findall(regex, string)` being: `regex = '([0-9]{5})'` (from what I understand the pattern was) and `string` the element from which you're extracting ZIP Codes.

```
import requests
import urllib.request,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('DOMAIN').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
tag_list = soup.find_all(name = 'tag_name')
match_list = []
for tag in tag_list:
    match_list.append(re.findall('([0-9]{5})', str(tag)))
```

You should watch out for possible matches that aren't ZIP codes. It could be the case of refining the `soup.find_all()` call by adding more arguments. The documentation might give you even more options, but the `attrs` argument could be set to `{'target_attribute':'target_att_value'}` those being an attribute and a value that definitely mark a tag with a ZIP code.

EDIT: Regarding possible empty elements, this link has a very straightforward solution: [Removing empty elements from an array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875595/removing-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-python/19875634)

Comment: PS: That regex only returns the ZIP Code. If you want more than that (like the whole text or the whole element, than you need to tweak the regex)

Comment: Thank you ! Works pretty good, just a hint for other users: It has to be "for tag in TAG_list".

Comment: If I print the match_list, it also shows the empty [ ] elements. What is the best way to just print the list elements which are not empty?

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. I'll fix it up!